# Mocking a service call of boolean type

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, moq

I have this method in my C# code:

```
public virtual bool VarselDAL_HentAvtaleForVarsling(
            DateTime varselDato, 
            out AvtaleForVarsling avtaleForVarsling)
```

which I'm trying to moq the service call. But I'm facing trouble with the `out`-parameter of my method.

Can anyone please hit me with right generics? I tried this one but of no use:

```
resMock.Setup(
           res => res.VarselDAL_HentAvtaleForVarsling(It.IsAny<DateTime>(), out _avtale))
                 .Returns(true).AtMostOnce().Verifiable()
```

Comment: [This blog might help](https://weblogs.asp.net/avnerk/moq-callbacks-and-out-parameters-a-particularly-tricky-edge-case)

Comment: OutCallback, and Callback() are used for method having void type. I have Boolean return type. I tried this, but the service call couldn't get mocked.
var avtaleForVarslin = new AvtaleForVarsling()
            {
//entered some values
            };
            resMock.Setup(res => res.VarselDAL_HentAvtaleForVarsling(It.IsAny<DateTime>(), out avtaleForVarslin))
            .Returns(true).AtMostOnce().Verifiable();